# ConcurrentQueue and Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach, concurrent-queue

I have a ConcurrentQueue with a list of URLs that I need to get the the source of. When using the Parallel.ForEach with the ConcurrentQueue object as the input parameter, the Pop method won't work nothing (Should return a string).

I'm using Parallel with the MaxDegreeOfParallelism set to four. I really need to block the number of concurrent threads. Is using a queue with Parallelism redundant?

Thanks in advance.

```
// On the main class
var items = await engine.FetchPageWithNumberItems(result);
// Enqueue List of items
itemQueue.EnqueueList(items);
var crawl = Task.Run(() => { engine.CrawlItems(itemQueue); });

// On the Engine class
public void CrawlItems(ItemQueue itemQueue)
{
Parallel.ForEach(
            itemQueue,
            new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4},
            item =>
            {

                var worker = new Worker();
                // Pop doesn't return anything
                worker.Url = itemQueue.Pop();
                /* Some work */
             });
 }

// Item Queue
class ItemQueue : ConcurrentQueue<string>
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<string> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

        public string Pop()
        {
            string value = String.Empty;
            if(this.queue.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception();
            this.queue.TryDequeue(out value);
            return value;
        }

        public void Push(string item)
        {
            this.queue.Enqueue(item);
        }

        public void EnqueueList(List<string> list)
        {
            list.ForEach(this.queue.Enqueue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: share your progress ...

Comment: ItemQueue should not both derive from `ConcurrentQueue` and contain a `ConcurrentQueue`, pick one.

Comment: @Zroq: Since downloading the source of a URL is an I/O-bound operation, I must state that parallelism is the wrong tool to use. Asynchronous concurrency would use far fewer resources and be just as fast.

Comment: @StephenCleary async/await with a SemaphoreSlim to force the number of active threads or there is another more efficient method?

Comment: @Zroq: `async` with `SemaphoreSlim` is what I would do.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `ConcurrentQueue<T>` if all you're going to do is to first add items to it from a single thread and then iterate it in `Parallel.ForEach()`. A normal `List<T>` would be enough for that.

Also, your implementation of `ItemQueue` is very suspicious:

- It inherits from `ConcurrentQueue<string>` and also contains another `ConcurrentQueue<string>`. That doesn't make much sense, is confusing and inefficient.
- The methods on `ConcurrentQueue<T>` were designed very carefully to be thread-safe. Your `Pop()` isn't thread-safe. What could happen is that you check `Count`, notice it's 1, then call `TryDequeue()` and not get any value (i.e. `value` will be `null`), because another thread removed the item from the queue in the time between the two calls.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with CrawlItems method, since you shouldn't call Pop in the action provided to the ForEach method. The reason is that the action is being called on each popped item, hence the item was already popped. This is the reason that the action has an 'item' argument.

I assume that you're getting null since all of the items already popped by the other threads, by the ForEach method.

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
public void CrawlItems(ItemQueue itemQueue)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
        itemQueue,
        new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4},
        item =>
        {
            worker.Url = item;
            /* Some work */
         });
}
```

Comment: After the itemQueue.EnqueueList(items); I've checked that the queue trully has 41 items

Comment: Could you please share the implementation if ItemQueue?